# Django: Sum of annotated field after grouping

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following two models:

```
class ProductionSet(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ProductionSetEntry(models.Model):
    productionset = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductionSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="set"
    )
    audited_at = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=_("Audited at"), null=True, blank=True
    )
```

What I want to achieve is a result set grouped for each line with two counts: an entries total count and a count for fully audited sets. Sample result:

```
<QuerySet [{'line': 1, 'sum_fully_audited': 0, 'total': 43}, {'line': 2, 'sum_fully_audited': 0, 'total': 51}, {'line': 3, 'sum_fully_audited': 2, 'total': 4}]>
```

I'm able to add the fully_audited to each row before grouping by:

```
ProductionSet.objects.annotate(
    audited=Count("set", filter=Q(set__audited_at__isnull=False)),
).annotate(
    fully_audited=Case(
        When(audited=Count("set"), then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
)
```

Following query:

```
ProductionSet.objects.annotate(
    audited=Count("set", filter=Q(set__audited_at__isnull=False)),
).annotate(
    fully_audited=Case(
        When(audited=Count("set"), then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).values(
    "line", "fully_audited"
).annotate(
    total=Count("id", distinct=True),
    sum_fully_audited=Sum("fully_audited"),
).order_by(
    "line"
)
```

raises `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('fully_audited'): 'fully_audited' is an aggregate` while

```
ProductionSet.objects.annotate(
    audited=Count("set", filter=Q(set__audited_at__isnull=False)),
).annotate(
    fully_audited=Case(
        When(audited=Count("set"), then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).values(
    "line", "fully_audited"
).annotate(
    total=Count("id", distinct=True),
).order_by(
    "line"
)
```

results in `<QuerySet [{'line': 1, 'fully_audited': 0, 'total': 43}, {'line': 3, 'fully_audi...` which looks good so far but obviously has no sum_fully_audited yet.

Comment: Remove the `fully_audited` from the `values(..)' in the third code fragment. It does not make any sense to both use it as value, and aggregate over it.

Comment: Sorry, this was a leftover. Bit it still results in `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('fully_audited'): 'fully_audited' is an aggregate`

Comment: Got any solution to the problem? I'm stuck with the same...